# Javascript not alerting input value

Tags: javascript, html, web

The code below isn't working as expected. I have excluded the rest of the tags. Whenever I execute the html, the alert alerts nothing at all. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

```
<p><input type="text" id = "earth"> Enter your weight on Earth.<BR><BR></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function calculate() 
    {
        var weight = input.earth.value;

        window.alert(weight);




    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually calling the `calculate()` function...

Comment: Where are you calling calculate() ?

Comment: As an aside, you have some problems with your HTML too...

Comment: I actually have called the calculate function,I forgot to show it here

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob then [edit] Your question and update the minimal code required to reproduce the issue. As of now, voting to close...

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting the element correctly - `input.earth` means nothing. You should use `getElementById()`:

```
var weight = document.getElementById('earth').value;
```

Comment: in my previous code, the format formid.elementid.value had worked perfectly

Comment: Does the `<form>` have an ID of `input`?

Comment: @TJ The OP stripped some tags out.

Comment: @Scimonster IKR, which is why I voted to close the question... It doesn't contain the minimal info required to reproduce it... It isn't a good idea to encourage such questions...

Answer (score 0):

you may try also:

```
<input type="text" id ="earth"> Enter your weight on Earth
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('earth').value)">alert</button>
```

Comment: add context and explain why this would be a solution to the problem